# linking libavcodec os x ffmpeg ApplicationServices.framework

Tags: ffmpeg, linker, clang, ld, osx-elcapitan

Here is my error: (newer version of ffmpeg)

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
  Referenced from: /Users/me/path/to/lib/libavcodec.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libavcodec.dylib requires version 64.0.0 or later, but ApplicationServices provides version 1.0.0
```

I have read the questions on SO that say you need to link ApplicationServices.framework... which I have done, it makes no difference...

I have searched for other versions of that framework:

```
$ mdfind ApplicationServices.framework
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework
```

just one...

so then inspecting frameworks...

```
$ otool -L /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices 
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 600.0.0)
...
```

and libavcodec

```
otool -L ../lib/libavcodec.dylib 
../lib/libavcodec.dylib:
    libavcodec.dylib (compatibility version 56.0.0, current version 56.60.100)
    @loader_path/libswresample.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version  ...
...
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 600.0.0)
```

I am compiling everything with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`

so maybe a bug in the toolchain?

compiler:

```
clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

linker:

```
ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-253.9
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a bug in clang, I re-installed Xcode 6.x and now the otool output of libavcodec is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 600.0.0)
```

which still doesn't match the output from the library itself... but it has a low enough compatibility version...  I will see if I can isolate and file a bug...

Comment: awesome... ran into this again... 7 months later, wasting time on the same issue...